# Recover Files from dead PC and Bitlocker Hardrive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, laptop, bitlocker

I have a Laptop with a dead screen, I do not want to fix it but I need those files in it.
The HDD have a BitLocker in it, how can I recover the files?

Comment: Do you have the BitLocker password, or the recovery key (that numeric password)?

Comment: I would suggest you to connect an external screen , then about how to recover the files with bitlocker, please refer to https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-recovery/bitlocker-data-recovery.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a yes as a response to the comment from user 1686:

You might connect an external screen to that laptop and use a function key combination to switch the display over to an external display.

If that is not possible you will have to remove the hard disk drive from the laptop and connect it to another windows machine supporting bitlocker.